# Create PDF from tall images (Automator?)

Tags: pdf, automator, graphics

I have a number of images that are 8.5" wide, but very long (around 40" tall) and I want to create a standard multi-paged 8.5" x 11" PDF document from all of the images. The problem is that the PDF will resize the images to fit the height of the PDF page or each page will be one image, which looks horrible.

Is there a way to do slice each image after multiples of 11" and combine those slices into a single PDF? I looked at Automator, but I couldn't find what I needed. If it's an application or script and not Automator, that's fine, too.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

[PosteRazor](http://posterazor.sourceforge.net/) is free, open source, and appears to do what you need. It takes a large image and splits it into a multi-page PDF.

As Nathan comments, the interface is pretty rough around the edges. [Tiler](http://www.macupdate.com/app/mac/20637/tiler) and [SplitPrint](http://itunes.apple.com/us/app/splitprint/id412574988?mt=12) are paid alternatives if you prefer a little more flexibility and an interface that's easier on the eyes.

Comment: +1 I've used PosteRazor. It works well, although the app's interface is a little ugly :P.

Comment: To put it mildly. I added a couple of paid alternatives with more polished interfaces.